# Easy way to test in two places?

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, dry, helper

**EDIT**

I did tons of research and concluded that I probably want to use a partial mock for this.  This led [to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13845331/794234) of what approach to use with my method mocking.

**Question**

When I use a helper class inside a method, I generally need to re-implement a lot (if not all) of the unit testing my helper class had.  That means every time I update a feature, I need to update the tests in *every place I use that feature*.  They're largely redundant (just some function names / mocking are different).

Any easy to way manage it?

**Highly Contrived Example**

Take this highly contrived example of a base class providing a basic utility function:

```vb
Public MustInherit Class SomeBase
    Public Property WebConnectionService As IWebConnectionService

    Public Overridable ReadOnly Property PortNumber As Integer
        Get
            Return 2352
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overridable ReadOnly Property Host As String
        Get
            Return "somesite.com"
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Sub OpenServiceConnection()
        ServiceConnection = WebConnectionService.OpenConnection(Host, PortNumber)
    End Sub
End Class

<TestFixture()> _
Public Class SomeBaseTest
    Private Class SomeBaseImpl
        Inherits SomeBase

        Public Overrides ReadOnly Property PortNumber As Integer
            Get
                Return 1
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Host As String
            Get
                Return "test.host"
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Sub New(w As IWebConnectionService)
            Me.WebConnectionService = w
        End Sub

        Public Sub Open()
            OpenServiceConnection()
        End Sub
    End Class

    <Test()> _
    Public Sub OpenServiceConnection_Should_Open_Connection_On_Set_Host_And_Port()
        Dim w As IWebConnectionService = MockRepository.GenerateMock(Of IWebConnectionService)()
        Dim s As New ServiceBaseImpl(w)

        s.Open()

        w.AssertWasCalled(Sub(wcs) wcs.OpenConnection(s.Host, s.PortNumber))
    End Sub
End Class
```

When I implement an actual some base service, I'll also want to verify the connection was opened, along these lines perhaps:

```vb
Public Class MyClass
    Inherits SomeBase

    Public Function GetData() As MyDataHolderClass
        OpenServiceConnection()

        '... other processing

        Return data
    End Function
End Class

<TestFixture()> _
Public Class MyClassTest
    <Test()> _
    Public Sub GetData_Should_Connect_To_The_Service()
        Dim w As IWebConnectionService = MockRepository.GenerateMock(Of IWebConnectionService)()
        Dim s As New MyClass(w)

        s.GetData()

        w.AssertWasCalled(Sub(wcs) wcs.OpenConnection(s.Host, s.PortNumber))
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Awesome Feature Suggestion for MS to Implement**

Really, I would like to be able to write a test which asserts the helper was used (and therefore all the passing tests on the helper apply here as well), but that violates the "only test the external interface of your code rule" (and I don't even know if it's possible).

```vb
<Test()> _
Public Sub GetData_Should_Call_OpenConnection_Helper()
   Dim s As New ServiceImpl()

   s.GetData()

   s.AssertCalledOpenConnectionHelper()
End Sub
```

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I intentionally left <kbd>vb.net</kbd> off because the question applies equally to all .Net languages.  My examples just happen to be in vb.net.