# Approach to unit testing interaction with a base class

Tags: .net, unit-testing, inheritance, rhino-mocks

There seems to be three general patterns for testing the way a derived class interacts with it's base<sup>1</sup>.  I don't really like any of them, for the reasons I've listed below.  Has anyone had long term success with one of these (or another) methods for testing base class interaction?

- [Change the access modifiers](http://geekswithblogs.net/MattRobertsBlog/archive/2008/12/16/how-to-make-a-quotprotectedquot-method-available-for-quotpartialquot-mocking-and-again.aspx) to allow `Friend` (`internal` in C#) access and set `InternalsVisibleTo` to include the mocking framework / unit test assembly

Changing the SUT to allow for testing is a *test smell*.  If the method is `Protected`, it's `Protected` because that's the appropriate design for it (I actually have yet to see what I would call a "valid" use of `Protected Friend` (`protected internal`)).

- [Use reflection and an extension method](http://ayende.com/blog/3044/dont-like-visibility-levels-change-that) to create an accessible version of the method you want to mock... then mock it

This requires a lot of extra work to mock a single method, it's not completely type-safe (e.g. a rename would kill it), and (at least in VB), requires creating a `Module` to put the method in to, which is a design nightmare (modules cannot go inside classes, so they need to be `Friend` at the most restricted, and you generics are more complicated)!

- Use state testing instead of behavior testing.

Depending on how complex the base class is, this can require *a lot* more tests than a single behavior test for the same thing.  Consider what would be required in state testing to match a `Me.AssertWasCalled(Function(s) s.SendMessage(messageText, [to]))` where `SendMessage` is a base class `Protected` method.

<sup>1</sup>NOTE: This is not necessary in Moq which supports mocking protected methods via `String` names of the method.  As Ayende mentions in the link above, he specifically avoided any non compile-time type safe mocking in Rhino Mocks (which I think is a good thing!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just my humble opinion.

Generaly it is not a good idea to test interactions with base class. As you are going to test *implementation details* here.

If testing inherited class togehter with base class seems to be complicated then it is probably time to refactor and use aggregation instead of inheritance?

Comment: Sometimes in testing the *implementation* I need to call into pre-implemented features from the base class.  Those features sometimes need mocking, which leads to the question above.

Comment: As for me, if I'm thinking about mocking base class methods then I actually should think about writting 2 separated classes. One shoud aggregate another one.

Comment: Aggregation is a *has a* relationship, I really want an *is a* relationship.  I could artificially change it, but that would mean changing the SUT for the sake of the test.

Comment: If I need *b is a* relationship then I definitely test *b* togehter with *a*. My test is **the specification**. Since *b* is also *a* then specification should also cover inherited from *a* functionality. And specification should not describe how *b* interacts with *a*.